# Angular material typography set up

Tags: angular, angular-material, typography

I can't get this working on my web app, so I created a new project (Angular 15) from the cli, and added material using "ng add @angular/material".

I edited app.component.html to be simply be

```
<div>
  <h1>This is an h1.</h1>
  <h2>This is an h2.</h2>
</div>
```

Now the good stuff. My styles.scss is

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

$my-typography: mat.define-typography-config();
@include mat.typography-hierarchy($my-typography);

$my-custom-typography-config: mat.define-typography-config(
  $headline-1: mat.define-typography-level(112px, 112px, 300, $letter-spacing: -0.05em),
);

@include mat.typography-hierarchy($my-custom-typography-config);
```

When I inspect the h1, Chrome DevTools shows
[image: dev tools image snip]

What am I missing to get this app to read the values I'm trying to set?
I tried setting it as part of a theme in my real app, but I couldn't get these typography settings working there either.

Comment: I'm starting to think the right answer is to just use plain ol' css.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you've added the class to your `index.html`. Verify whether the `<body>` tag includes the `class="mat-typography"`. If it's missing, add it like this:

```html
<body class="mat-typography">
```

Comment: Yep, got that. It's added by that 'ng add'.

Comment: Could you share the full code of styles.scss?

Comment: That was the full file. The documentation looked like the typography should work without defining palettes so I was trying to go as simple as I could.